# How to know if time part was present when parsing with DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datetime

Say, I have two strings containing date/time in arbitrary user-provided format for an arbitrary culture:

```
string str1 = "6/19/2013";
string str2 = "6/19/2013 1 am";
```

I can parse them by doing:

```
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Parse(str1);
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Parse(str2);
```

But how do I know if the time part was present & parsed into the DateTime object?

Comment: My immediate reaction would be to test if the time component of the resulting datetime is not midnight - but I'm guessing you'd need to know if they supplied 12 am in the string, right?

Comment: @DanP: If time was not provided by a user I need to set it to either 00:00:00 or 23:59:59, depending on some other variable. So checking for 12 am would not work.

Comment: Does your input have a specific format, or are you allowing *anything* that `DateTime.Parse` can parse?

Comment: @Jason: No. The format is culture specific. It is not necessarily US English, as in my example.

Comment: You should be careful using `DateTime.Parse` without a culture parameter.  Inputs can be ambiguous across cultures (e.g. 1/2/2001 can be January 2 or February 1 depending on the date format).

Comment: @Ben Reich: `DateTime.Parse(string)` assumes the current culture.

Comment: i guess you should fix the *arbitrary user-provided format* part since you no longer control the day and month part and this could lead to some different valid dates but not the one intended. It is good to know that it would be n say `dd/MM/yyyy` format else you could mess up for `06/12/2013` and `12/06/2013` now what would be that if the format is not fixed

Answer (score 1):

What do you guys think about something like this?

```
public static DateTime ParseDateTimeWithTimeDifferentiation(string str, out bool bOutTimePresent)
{
    //Parse date/time from 'str'
    //'bOutTimePresent' = receives 'true' if time part was present
    DateTime dtRes;

    //Get formats for the current culture
    DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat;

    DateTimeStyles dts = DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces | 
        DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal;

    //Get all formats
    string[] arrFmts = dtfi.GetAllDateTimePatterns();

    foreach (string strFmt in arrFmts)
    {
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(str, strFmt, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, dts, out dtRes))
        {
            //Parsed it!

            //These format codes come from here:
            // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx
            bOutTimePresent = strFmt.IndexOfAny(new char[] { 'H', 'h', 'm', 's', 'f', 'F', 't', 'z' }) != -1;

            return dtRes;
        }
    }

    //As a fall-back, just parse it as-is
    dtRes = DateTime.Parse(str);

    //Assume it has time, as otherwise we'd catch the date-only above
    bOutTimePresent = true;

    return dtRes;
}
```

Comment: +1 I didn't know about `GetAllDateTimePatterns`.  Instead of checking `strFmt` for that list of time-related characters, you could also call `ToString(strFmt)` on a new `DateTime` with a non-midnight time set, parse it, and see that the time was kept.  This would protect against custom date patterns being added in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using two separate calls to `DateTime.ParseExact` or `DateTime.TryParseExact`.  This will be especially easy if you know the format of the date and time parts.  The code would look something like this:

```
DateTime dateValue;
var culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "M/d/yyyy H:mm:ss", culture, 
                       DateTimeStyles.None, out dateValue))) {
     //Using date and time.  dateValue var is set.
}
else if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "M/d/yyyy", culture, 
                       DateTimeStyles.None, out dateValue))) {
    //Using just date.  dateValue var is set.
}
```

If you cannot anticipate the exact format of the date/time string, you can either enumerate a bunch of possible possible formats, or use regular expressions to try to extract the time part.  Read more about custom date and time formats [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).  There are also some provided [standard date and time formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx).

Comment: That is a good approach. Except two things. 1. It ties it to US English. As I said, the culture is not known up front. 2. I'd start parsing dates-only first. There's less variables there. Don't you think? As for regexp, that is not possible. How would I know the format, IDK, for Arabic?

Comment: @c00000fd I hadn't read the comment regarding the culture being unknown.  Unless you can list out every culture that might be used, this approach probably won't work.

Comment: @c00000fd As a note, you can always use `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` to get the current culture.  Since you were currently using `DateTime.Parse` without a culture parameter, maybe you're OK with assuming current culture.

Comment: How does this address the midnight case?

Comment: @AdrianHum If there is no time present, then using `TryParseExact` with `M/d/yyyy H:mm:ss` will return false (and the `out` variable will not be set) and custom logic can be implemented in the `if` block.  If the exact time of midnight is provided, it can be dealt with there.

Answer (score -1):

If no time was specified in the string that was parsed, the `TimeOfDay` property of the `DateTime` object will be set to midnight (00:00:00). You can then check if that's the case with something like this:

```
if (dt1.TimeOfDay.Equals(new TimeSpan(0,0,0))) {
  //do something
} else {
  //do something else
}
```

EDIT: Another approach could be to separate the date and time sections of the string. This is assuming some type of numerical date format is passed using dashes, commas, or anything besides spaces.

```
string[] dateString = str1.Split(' ');
string[] date2String = str2.Split(' ');
```

You'll now have a string array that can be easily used to check for special values. `dateString[0]`, for example, should contain your entire date. `dateString[1]` and beyond will have any time formats, and can be recombined and parsed into a `TimeSpan` object. Obviously if you have only a single entity in the array, they've not entered any time.

Comment: What if a user explicitly specified time as such: `6/19/2013 12:00 AM`?

Comment: I added another possible solution ... a little bit of string manipulation.

Comment: @Matt Johnson: You're assuming too much about the culture.

Comment: @c00000fd consider this `07/03/2013`now is it `3 July` or `7 march` ?